# eventAction and pageView filters in one request

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dashboard

I'm trying to filter website conversions from Google Analytics for a dashboard. However since it is a mixture of third party leads, events, and page path that contribute to the leads, I have to combine different types of filters. However combining folling metrics, the https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ shows me the value 0 even if that's not correct.

Metrics: ga:totalEvents 
Dimension:ga:date
ga:pagePath=@DialogNavigatorVertical,ga:eventAction==Texting form submit

I have tried multiple solutions, but can't figure out how to get the correct data. Can I not combine pagePath and evenAction?

Thank you so much for all your kind help,

Anna

Answer (score 1):

Events by definition are not page views. This means that an Event dimension (category, action, label) *can't have page view metrics such as page views or average time on the page* because that information does not relate to the specific event.

But you can definitely combine `pagePath` and `evenAction`. You are getting wrong results because of one of the following reasons

- In your filter, `ga:pagePath=@DialogNavigatorVertical` is wrong, it must be either == or !=. it cant be an assignment operator
- IF you wish to combine two filter conditions using **AND** that means both must be true, use `;`. Semicolon is used for `AND` operator in filters
- IF you wish to combine two filter conditions using **OR** that means both must be true, use `,`. Comma is used for `OR` operator in filters
- In case you are using core reporting api from a backend script, please URL encode the call before hitting. like `==` must be `%3D%3D`, space must be `%20` and so on.

Please have a look into settings here : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Comment: Hello Thushar,

Thank you so much for helping me with this.

I'm confused since
[using the @ operator is the only time I would get the correct results ( 78 pageviews)][1].However when I add another filter with "," (OR) "ga:pagePath=@DialogNavigatorVertical.aspx,ga:eventAction==Texting form submit" it [becomes 0][2].
I understand that events are not by definition pageviews. So how can I pull this a data in one string to received one total value for my dashboard?

Thanks again for your support!Anna

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAtiH.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBNvh.png

Comment: Oh sorry for the typo - Tushar!